# Code-compliant undercabinet light wiring

Tags: electrical, lighting, code-compliance

I have 6 LED undercabinet lights that I plan to link together and power using a switched outlet. The lights use SPT-2 linking cables with proprietary connectors that aren't long enough to link the lights so that the cord is hidden. I would like to use a spool of SPT-2 wire to connect these lights, but according to the NEC, SPT-2 wire can't be spliced (I would need to splice to connect the lights with the proprietary connectors; essentially I am just extending the linking cables). Can SPT-2 wire connections be made in a UL-compliant junction box mounted to the underside of the cabinets?

Here's an example of the junction box: https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Direct-Wire-Linkable-Fixture-Junction-Converter-Box-White-39971/304228493

This box is intended for the connection of AC power to the proprietary connectors, but I was wondering if I could use several of these boxes to make connections between SPT-2 wire and the linking cables. I am not sure if this would constitute a violation of code. Linking cables are available on Amazon, but they aren't long enough.

Edit: here's the lights I'm using - https://byjasco.com/honeywell-18in-linkable-plug-led-under-cabinet-fixture

Comment: Just want to put this out there - if you use led lights that are low voltage, you can basically do whatever you want with the wiring, and you're not sacrificing anything since _all_ LED lights are low voltage at their heart.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need a different box

The fixtures you're looking at use a different converter box than what you have linked.  In particular, you'll need a Jasco 44130 box in order to transition from the connectors on the lights you've linked to permanent wiring. For your application, you'll need one of those boxes at each end of the connection, with a Chapter 3 wiring method between them, such as 14/2 NM cable if the wiring is concealed appropriately, or a surface raceway (Wiremold) with 14AWG stranded THHNs in it if you want to run exposed wiring box to box.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just to clarify, the power source will be a switched outlet that the first light will be plugged into before being linked to the other lights, the converter box will not be hardwired directly. So the switched outlet will be connected to the first converter box with SPT-2/wall plug, where it powers the first light. The linking cable leaving the first light will return to that box and will be connected to 2 THHNs, which will be used to provide power to the next converter box powering another light, and so on. Does that sound right?

Comment: @33dst if you're using THHNs, they'll need to be in a Chapter 3 raceway (conduit or wiremold, in otherwords)